# How to use lightgbm in community version of pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, lightgbm

I am trying use lightgbm package in pycharm, however when I try to do that, it requires me to buy some pro requirements plugin, even though on other platforms there is no problem using lightgbm library. I wanted to ask maybe I am doing something wrong?
Is there a free way to use lightgbm in pycharm? Here is the problem:

[image]